# Eclipse error when installing Java 14 support for Eclipse 2020-03 (4.15) plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I want to install Java 14 support for Eclipse 2020-03 (4.15) but I'm getting an error.

My eclipse version is 2020-03 (4.15.0).

I go to the Marketplace, I look for "Java 14" and I select the plugin I mentioned, I choose the two solutions that are required and I click Confirm.

I get this error: **The following solutions are not available: Java 14 support for Eclipse 2020-03 (4.15) Proceed with the installation anyways?**

Comment: An installed plug-in may prevent you from installing the Java 14 support. The reason and details are shown in the installation dialog. If there's anything you don't understand, add it to your question. Please note that there are different Eclipse IDE packages. So it is unclear which one do you have, which additional plug-ins you have intalled and which, in your case, two solutions are required you have chosen.